# Box2d Libgdx Velocity skips too many pixels so I can't stop where I want

Tags: box2d, libgdx

So my screen is 1280x720 with the following setup:

```
static final float BOX_STEP=1/60f;  
static final int BOX_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS=6;  
static final int BOX_POSITION_ITERATIONS=2;  
static final float WORLD_TO_BOX=0.01f;  
static final float BOX_TO_WORLD=100f;
```

As you can see am using pretty normal parameter here. I set the velocity of an object as follows:

```
    if(screenX - slimeBody.getPosition().x * BOX_TO_WORLD > 0)
        velocity = 8;
    else
        velocity = -8;

    slimeBody.setLinearVelocity(velocity, 0);
            target = screenX;
```

But then I want to stop at a given point and I use the following function:

```
if(slimeBody.getPosition().x * BOX_TO_WORLD +10 > target && slimeBody.getPosition().x * BOX_TO_WORLD < target)
        slimeBody.setLinearVelocity(0,0);
```

Now I don't like using this because it produces jitters when moving the object side to side quickly. This is because the moment I set a velocity for the object, it goes so fast it skips a ton of coordinates, in pixels am talking anywhere from 10-20 and in meters from .10-.20

It is crucial for me to detect movement down to the millimeter. Now if you gonna tell me to take down the velocity, than the movement is too slow for my purpose. Anyway to force the object to register more pixels,coordinates when traveling so I can stop it more precisely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will make an assumption that you are only interested in immediately stopping at the target position instead of slowing down. I also will assume you are only moving in the x direction and you are not interested in the y component.

A simple way to solve this problem is to find the distance between your current position and the target position. So if you are at (10, 10) and your target is (20, 10) the distance will be 10. Say you are moving at 180 units / second, which means 3 units / frame @ 60 fps. It should be pretty clear that you will not be able to stop at the target because 3 frames is too  soon and 4 frames is too long. Instead, we need to interpolate between frames to determine if we can reach our target 'during' the frame.

This isn't too hard, we know how fast we are going, we know our current location, and we know where we want to go. On the third frame we will be at (19, 10) and our target is (20, 10). Math.abs(20 - 19) < 3, thus we can set the position to be (20, 10) and set our velocity to 0.

This is only one solution to the problem you are facing, but one of the simplest. Hope it helps :)